# Nexus S Update 4.0.4 screen sensitivity issue?

Tags: updates, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen, touchscreen

I updated my Nexus S to Android 4.0.4, which is amazing for battery charge time, but I have a problem with touch sensitivity.  It's lagging and registering touches in place that I did not touch.

Anyone face this problem?

Any advice to avoid this problem?